# How to make two divs stay on the same line

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am learning bootstrap 5 and will like to keep my links and the label "Testing" on one line. I used the text-start and text-end thinking that will do it but no it did not. How can I make this stay on the same line? Here is my fiddle.

```html
<body>
    <section id="firstMenu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="same-line">
                <div class="text-start">
                    <h2>TESTING</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="text-end px-2">
                    <ul class="mymenu">
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qrfokhvn/

Comment: use the bootstrap navbar component. Its pretty much exactly what you ware wanting to do. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

```
.same-line {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

`d-flex` or `d-inline-flex` in the parent element will set your elements in a ***flex*** display.

[Bootstrap Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

li+li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <section id="firstMenu">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="same-line d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="text-start">
          <h2>TESTING</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="text-end px-2">
          <ul class="mymenu d-flex">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 5 not 4. Does this work with Bootstrap 5?

Comment: @user2320476 yes... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: @user2320476 updated answer with latest version of BS v5